# How do I secure my REST api developed in playframework

Tags: api, security, rest, playframework

I have read a lot about this on here and other articles. First let me explain my situation.

Let's say I have the following REST backend:

`GET /user` returns all users in JSON. (No need to be logged-in)
`POST /user` registers new user.  (No need to be logged-in)
`DELETE /user` deletes a user. (You **do** need to be logged-in)

`POST /login` posts login credentials and returns a 200 OK on succesful authentication. Also this creates a `session` with the `username`.

`DELETE /login` logout, this deletes the session.

For user authentication and roles I use Deadbolt-2 so for example when `DELETE /user` is called first the `session` will be viewed to determine whether you are logged-in and then the `username` is used to determine if you have the correct permissions.

This **works**. My question is not about this kind of authorization/authentication. It is however about the following:

I want to secure the "public" API calls like: `GET /user` in a way so only front-end applications that are ***approved by me*** can access them.

I have read a lot about api-keys and HMAC and oAuth. But it seems to me they are talking about the first scenario and not the second. So how would I go about this in my situation ?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Logins and granting access only to approved clients are _sort of the same thing_. You have to keep a list of all approved clients. How else are you going to know if the client may access your API? Also, the client has to identify itself somehow. This identification process has to contain _a secret_ between you and the client. Otherwise, what stops me from telling you: _"Hi, I'm client XY, gimme API!"_, even though I'm not on your list. This is (on a basic level) equivalent to a username/password-based login. Or giving out "API keys".

Comment: So I should implement an extra basic level of authorization below the ones I have right now for my front-end to automatically log-in with ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You might find this [Securing Single Page Apps and REST Services](http://www.jamesward.com/2013/05/13/securing-single-page-apps-and-rest-services) article by [James Ward](https://stackoverflow.com/users/77409/james-ward) useful, it's built using Play Framework, Java, jQuery, and CoffeeScript.

The reference source is here: https://github.com/jamesward/play-rest-security/

Comment: I found this about 2 hours ago by myself actually. This in combination with Carsten's comment is really helping me.