# Securing a REST API developed with Play Framework

Tags: api, rest, security, http, playframework

I am currently developing a REST/JSON API using Play Framework 2.3. I am currently thinking about an efficient yet simple way to secure the API. By security, I mean that some actions need the end user to be authenticated to be accepted.

For the moment, I was relying on Play Framework session management (as a reminder, it stores all the session data in a signed cookie which is sent in every query - as such, it is stateless and even though the cookie can be read by the client, it cannot be updated).

The flow is quite simple:

1. The end-user logins thanks to the API client sending a login query
2. If accepted, a cookie is set in the reply
3. When sending next queries, the API client automatically adds the cookie, thus the end user is recognized by the API

My question is the following: do I really need to go further in term of security? I can't find a reason why this existing mechanism would not work correctly...

Thanks in advance!

PS: for the moment I am both developer and consumer of the API, and there's no plan for releasing it publicly.

PPS: the client I am developing is a simple webapp using AngularJS

Comment: I don't understand the question because "further" is very broad. Why are you imposing further security restrictions on yourself knowing you are the only consumer? What are you concerned about - just general security best practices, integrity of the framework's security, or something else?

Comment: It's true that as I said, the API is not public. In that context, it's just to ensure I don't forget something big which could cause a security hole (so yeah best practices). But to be honest, my question also applies to others use cases with a public API.

Comment: Check out this article which explains cross site request forgery in the context of play [18076206](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18076206/how-do-i-secure-my-rest-api-developed-in-playframework?rq=1) and play's own [documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/ScalaCsrf) on the issue

Answer (score 1):

You do not need. This is correct solution.

You can think to go to the tokens only in the terms of usability.

Of course I assume that you use https.

Comment: Yep it's based on HTTPs.

Comment: So I do not see any secure reason to use tokens (JWT). Different aspects - yes, tokens is more "REST" way and more flexible. One  more thing about cookies - it is even a little bit safe that other headers, but only a little bit - such things like "HTTPOnly" and "Secure".

Comment: Instead of set the value in cookie, you can try with Http header x-auth-token. Still it's not a rule to follow,  but it's the standard for Token based authentication